# Invalid Operation Exception when trying to AppendText to a RichTextBox using an extension method

Tags: c#, forms, richtextbox

I have this extension method for a RichTextBox provided by another question on StackOverflow.

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
    {
        public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
        {
            box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
            box.SelectionLength = 0;

            box.SelectionColor = color;
            box.AppendText(text);
            box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
        }
    }
```

I'm attempting to use it like so:

```
public void Write(string Text)
        {
            Color Green = Color.Green;
            TxtBox.AppendText(Text, Green);
        }
```

However, when I run this I get

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Does anyone have any idea as to what could be going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to access your `RichTextBox` in a different thread ? May be a Timer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works, but it seems you are trying to access to your richtextbox from a different thread other than UI thread.

You can change your extension method as follows:

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
    {
        if (box.InvokeRequired)
            box.Invoke((Action)(() => AppendText(box, text, color)));
        else
        {
            box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
            box.SelectionLength = 0;

            box.SelectionColor = color;
            box.AppendText(text);
            box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
        }

    }
}
```